KVM switches not working after upgrade to 24.04
I upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04 & KVM switch stopped working (mostly mouse & keyboard, but also video occasionally. Tried 3 different brands of KVM, switched all cables, mice & keyboards.  Same behavior.  Downgraded to 23.10 & all worked again.

How did you downgrade? What is the actual question?

since the problem went away when you "downgraded" I am voting to close this question as "not reproducible or relevant only for a specific time".

I did a clean reinstall of Mantic (23.10.1) on both machines.  How is this not relevant?  It is very reproducible.  I did the same with a third machine - same thing.  It has to be a problem with KVM switches in 24.04

Consider reporting a bug. Bugs are off topic here.

I just want to add for everyone looking for a quick solution (since I got here having a similar problem). Switching to 24.10 also works, it is just the LTS that has problems.

Thank you, Tim!
